# TinyMCE + html5 figure, img & figcaption plugin/insertion

Tags: html, tinymce, django-tinymce

I'm looking for a best practice approach to achieving a plugin in TinyMCE, to implement insertion of the HTML5 element `<figure>`, along one or more child `<img>`s, and a `<figcaption>`.

Whilst the HTML5 spec seems to allow for other figure types, i.e. other than `<img>`, that's all we're concerned with at the moment.

Ideally, the solution would be plugin based and portable.

FYI we're using TinyMCE w/ Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the [extended_valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aextended_valid_elements) setting to configure your elements as valid elements and define valid children.

Comment: Good answer for the moment, but would love to have something more specific.

Comment: That is how to make sure it doesn't strip your `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` tags, but this doesn't support the actual insertion. :(

Comment: @Kerrick: insertion shouldn't be a problem. how do you try to insert it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to create a button (like the B button for strong tags) that'll insert a `<figcaption>` so my users don't have to edit the HTML source.

Comment: @Kerrick: have a look here: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Creating_a_plugin

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=29615

It is a small modification of the image plugin so that it uses figure/figcaption when it is the case. It was never used in production, but should work.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: This link is dead